# Const-correctness in C pointer-to-pointer parameters

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently working on a project to get into more advanced concepts of C. One of the concepts I want to learn about is const-correctness, so I decided to make my entire codebase abide by this idea.

Say we have a function like this:

```cpp
/*
 * Creates and displays a window.
 * 
 * Returns non-zero on failure, 0 on success.
 */
extern int window_create(
    _In_z_   char const *const pz_title, /* window title */
             uint32_t width,             /* width in pixels */
             uint32_t height,            /* height in pixels */
             bool isvsync,               /* Should VSync be enabled? */
    /*
     * Pointer to a pointer to a "window" structure
     * that will receive the freshly-created window. 
     * Must not be NULL.
     */
    _Outptr_ struct window **pps_window
);
```

A window will be created, and the pointer pointed to by `pps_window` will then point to the newly-created window struct.

Now, should I enforce const-correctness on the `window **` parameter as well? Like so:

```cpp
struct window **const pps_window
```

The thing is, in my opinion, because the pointer to the pointer itself is passed-by-value anyway, wouldn't explicitly marking it as const be somewhat pointless because the caller does not have to care if the pointer-to-pointer copy on the stack gets modified, or would it  still be good practice to add it nonetheless?

Comment: Start from one question. What is constant there? Struct? Pointer to struct? or pointer to pointer to struct? Or maybe some combination of those. When you answer this question you will know how to declare your functions and data. BTW the rest of the parameters should be const as well as you will not change it

Comment: It is fine to declare parameters `const` if the function should not modify them. It can help catch typos that would accidentally modify a parameter. However, it has effect only in function definitions. Qualifiers on parameters in declarations that are not definitions have no effect. (Qualifiers “inside” the type, not at its top level, do have effect. In a parameter declaration `const int * const x`, the type of `x` is always a pointer to a `const int`, but `x` itself is `const` only in a function declaration.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil if typos are motivation then IMO something is wrong

Comment: @0___________: Typos are a large source of errors and are a significant driver of why things should be declared before they are used, why type systems exist, and other important parts of language design.

Comment: The first `const` says that what the pointer points to can _not_ be modified (i.e. the string is R/O). The second `const` says that the variable `pz_title` can never point to anything else. The first says `*pz_title = 'a';` is illegal. The second says that `pz_title = "foo bar";` is illegal. IMO, while the first has great utility, the second one is of marginal value. It does _not_ help with optimization because the compiler can detect this on its own (because it can see all changes to the variable). In 40 years of C code, I've never used the 2nd `const`. To me, it's just extra clutter.

Comment: Technically, only the pointer-to-pointer itself is constant (i.e. the address we want to write the pointer to), the pointer that's being pointed to is non-const as it will be specifically written to, and the structure itself (whose pointer is going to be written into ```*pps_window```) is also non-const as there will be some initialization that's going to be done through *pps_window as well.

Comment: @CraigEstey This is basically my train of thought. That's why I think that the const in ```struct window **const pps_window``` is somewhat pointless. 
So the entire thing is basically about consistency. It would be consistent to add it whereever it fits and technically makes sense, but often it would be meaningless to everybody except maybe the compiler.

Comment: As @0___________ mentioned, I could go as far as declaring every parameter const, but does it make sense (i.e. is it good practice) to be so pedantic about it?

Comment: @cocoz1 My personal anecdote: The only time I've seen 2nd const was 10 years ago at work. We had a guy who was fastidious about using it. But, he also was the worst coder we had. The 2nd const didn't prevent him from producing code laced with subtle bugs. So, it's become a personal red flag. In c++, you may want the attribute for `this`: `void foo::set(int xval) { this->xval = yval; }` You wouldn't want any function to be able to change `this`

Comment: @CraigEstey: Re “it can see all changes to the variable”: That is not universally true. The address of a parameter could be taken and used computationally in ways the compiler cannot analyze. Declaring it `const` prevents taking its address to use as a pointer to non-`const` without some manual override by the programmer, such as a cast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help as I don't really understand your question...

C does things the C way. Ask yourself the question what will happen in the following code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void change_i(int*);


int main() {

  const int i = 5;
  const int const* pi = &i;

  // doesn't compile as expected...
  //i = 1;
  //*pi = 1;

  printf("i is: %d\n", i);

  change_i(pi);
  printf("i is: %d\n", i);

}


void change_i(int* i) {
  *i = 6;
}
```

What output are we expecting? We would think that i remains 5 right? Though C does not really care... I like to see pointers and const pointers as data types as well, some might say I'm wrong, some will agree, and what happens whit C is that we do have some kind of notion of datatypes but since C is weakly typed everything is essentially the same type, being "a pile of bits". In this example, C casts the const pointer to a "normal" pointer in the function change_i. Here is the result:

```
i is: 5
i is: 6
```

That doesn't mean const is useless, what it does is say "I cannot change!", which does have an impact at compile time... A way to implicitly avoid writing hacky code like I just showed would be trough, example give, typedefs:

```
typedef const int const* * const* my_special_integer_type;


my_special_integer_type i = ...;

void do_something(my_special_integer_type i) {
  /*
   * code...
   */
}
```

Just to give an idea, hope this helped...

Comment: Basically, it's about whether I should be really pedantic about consting everything that should not be modified (even non-pointer arguments) even though the caller will not notice it, or whether I should just const things that might have side effects outside of the function's scope.
It's not a big deal after all, I just like things clean and consistent, and before I start philosophizing about such a thing that might have multiple answers, I just went on here to ask other, perhaps more knowledgeable people than me.

Comment: It depends, should a value be allowed to change? Than no, no const needed, should it absolutely never ever but never change? Than yes, const the value, but be consistent. A function from some library might take a const char* instead of char* to indicate to the programmer that this particular function will not change it. On the other hand some library might ask a const pointer to tell the programmer "hey, I need this const, don't change it ever please!". In C it especially in C these kind of things allways "depend".